# copying an Apple Mac Hard Drive from a dead mac?

Tags: macos, hardware, hard-drive

I have little experience with macs so I thought I would ask a quick question before I go ahead with this.

My friend's 6 year old mac desktop died the other day, she took it into the tech guys at the apple store to find out if she can get her documents back and they said no because the hard drive is in a different code you can't take it out.

That sounds like a load of crap to me so I want to rip out the hard drive and plug it into my PC then copy everything over. I also have access to linux if I need to.

So is there anything I need to know before doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: "in a different code you can't take it out"? Seriously? Those "geniuses"...

Comment: you gotta love apple store people haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the hard drive itself isn't dead, you can get your hands on something like Ubuntu and copy all the files onto a different hard drive.  You usually can't do this from windows because windows uses NTFS file system and will not recognize the mac file system ([HFS or HFSPlus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system#Mac_OS_X)).  Most flavors of linux can recognize mac hard drives and copy the contents.  There can be some tricks with ownership of the files so here's a good post on how to do this in ubuntu:

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-852144.html

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If your friend plans on buying a new Mac, you should keep the disk itself; with an external HDD enclosure, a new machine (or a new OSX installation) will be able to migrate basically everything from the old drive.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, I know, but I just rescued a broken mac disk using dd_rescue, booting Trinity 3.4 on a HP and cloning the broken disk to a working disk. Then I popped the working disk into a working mac and hey presto, the user got the files back.